# Thermistor Datasheet Reading

Tags: arduino, datasheet, thermistor

I have the following datasheet for a thermisistor:
http://make-documents.s3.amazonaws.com/UGulDNLaIajWgPom.pdf

I am trying to use the formula (found here http:// iwantmyreal.name/blog/2012/09/23/measuring-the-temperature-with-an-arduino-and-a-thermistor/):
$$
1/T=1/T_0+1/B*ln(R/R_0)
$$
I am not sure I'm using the correct values, my understanding is that the values provided in the datasheet are as follow: $$R_0=20,000 ohm,$$ $$T_0=25 C,$$ $$Beta=4300$$ Can anyone confirm that this is correct?

I'm trying to get a temperature reading out of that sensor using an Arduino UNO microcontroller using the following found at http://playground.arduino.cc//ComponentLib/Thermistor2 at the bottom where it says example #2 using numbers instead of episco k164 definition .... (substituting with the above values)

The results are ~41.96 degrees F, and the room is between 75-80 degrees F so that means the temperatures readings are way off, I don't understand why unless I got the wrong values from the datasheet. Also I have two of these sensors and both give about the same value.

Code currently using:

```
// Code obtained from http://playground.arduino.cc//ComponentLib/Thermistor2
#include <math.h>
// enumarating 3 major temperature scales
enum {
  T_KELVIN=0,
  T_CELSIUS,
  T_FAHRENHEIT
};

// manufacturer data for episco k164 10k thermistor
// simply delete this if you don't need it
// or use this idea to define your own thermistors
#define EPISCO_K164_10k 4300.0f,298.15f,10000.0f  // B,T0,R0

// Temperature function outputs float , the actual 
// temperature
// Temperature function inputs
// 1.AnalogInputNumber - analog input to read from 
// 2.OuputUnit - output in celsius, kelvin or fahrenheit
// 3.Thermistor B parameter - found in datasheet 
// 4.Manufacturer T0 parameter - found in datasheet (kelvin)
// 5. Manufacturer R0 parameter - found in datasheet (ohms)
// 6. Your balance resistor resistance in ohms  

float Temperature(int AnalogInputNumber,int OutputUnit,float B,float T0,float R0,float     R_Balance)
{
  float R,T;

  R=(1024.0f*R_Balance/float(analogRead(AnalogInputNumber)))-R_Balance;
  T=1.0f/(1.0f/T0+(1.0f/B)*log(R/R0));

  switch(OutputUnit) {
    case T_CELSIUS :
      T-=273.15f;
    break;
    case T_FAHRENHEIT :
      T=9.0f*(T-273.15f)/5.0f+32.0f;
    break;
    default:
    break;
  };

  return T;
}

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

 Serial.println("*************************");
 Serial.println("10k Balance");
 Serial.println(Temperature(0,T_FAHRENHEIT,4300.0f,298.15f,20000.0f,9770.0f));
 //Serial.println(Temperature(1,T_FAHRENHEIT,4300.0f,298.15f,20000.0f,9770.0f));
 Serial.println("*************************");

 delay(500);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a schematic/code? What value resistor are you using for the balance resistor?

Comment: Sure. If you look at "Thermistor Test Schematic" Under http://playground.arduino.cc//ComponentLib/Thermistor2 that's pretty much it, except I'm using a 9.77 Kohm resistor (I measured it with a Voltmeter). Or +5V --> thermistor <-- Node 1 --> 9.77kohm --> ground. Then I have a connection from Node 1 to port A0 of the arduino uno microcontroller. I hope it makes sense, let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: That's a start, thanks (it's usually a good idea to include the schematic and any code for *your* setup, so everyone knows exactly what you are doing) What is the *exact* code you are using?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will do for next time. The code is the following:

Comment: See above in the original question for my exact code, site won't let me edit my last comment.

Comment: @joze adding a circuit to this post is really something you should consider. Saying you will do it the next time is like me saying "I'll answer his next question". It's not much to ask that you make life a little easier for the guys who are providing you with an answer to your problem.

Comment: Have you measured the resistance of the NTC? The voltage on the analog input?

Comment: @Andyaka -- My apologies, what I meant was, here's a link for the diagram (for this time), next time I will include it in the question, I didn't mean it in a rude way. I will research how to draw circuits since I don't have PSPICE anymore.

Comment: @starblue -- Yes I did. As a matter of fact, I did the calculations manually, and it gave 46.35 degrees Celsius. The voltage was 3.65V. The resistance for thermistor was 19.54kohm, and used the Beta of 4300 as provided in the datasheet and 25 degress Celsius at my T_0. So this leads me to think I got the wrong datasheet or something else; the error in the thermistors according to the datasheet is between +/- 0.5C. The thermistors are from this kit I bought at radioshack: http://makezine.com/shed/ultimate-microcontroller-pack/ Any ideas of possible error, or is there any calibration needed? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in knowing how I solved this problem, I used the AREF and 3.3V from the Arduino microcontroller connected directly one of sides of the thermistors. I believe the voltage coming out of my laptop was dropping; USB +5V was dropping to ~4.7V thus making my calculations lower.

Here's the website which helped to find my answer (this site includes CODE and DIAGRAM):

http://learn.adafruit.com/thermistor/using-a-thermistor

Thanks everyone for your help.